# How to chain two Imagemagick Commands

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have two dependent imagemagick commands, which work well on their own, but having tried every invocation imaginable, I cannot combine them to work as one. I would be so grateful, if someone could point me in the right direction.

I have tried a variety of methods to combine the two using online resources as a guide, but as per usual, I cannot find an exact example to fit my needs. I am running on IM6* (my server is also on IM6*)

The first command takes a centre crop thumbnail of an image and then makes a circular image of it.

```
convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 face.png \
-thumbnail 31x31^ -gravity center -extent 31x31 \
\( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw 'circle 15,12 12,0' \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite cut_to_fit_circ.png
```

The second command takes the above output and "flattens it" onto another image

```
convert marker.svg -page -1+2 cut_to_fit_circ.png \
-flatten facemarker.jpg
```

I should end up with an svg image with the circular image on top of the marker.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this is ImageMagick 6.

```
convert marker.svg -page -1+2 \
\( -define jpeg:size=200x200 face.png \
-thumbnail 31x31^ -gravity center -extent 31x31 \
\( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw 'circle 15,12 12,0' \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \) \
-flatten facemarker.jpg
```

If that does not work, then post links to your face.png and marker.svg so I can see those files and use them to test.

Also why the -page for only a couple of pixels?

CORRECTION:

The issue is that the -compose copy_opacity flows over to the -flatten. So you have to reset to -compose over before flattening. The corrected command would be.

```
convert -background none marker.svg \
\( -page +0+0 -define jpeg:size=200x200 face.png \
-thumbnail 31x31^ -gravity center -extent 31x31 \
\( +clone -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw 'circle 15,12 12,0' \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \) \
-compose over -flatten facemarker.png
```

[image]

Adjust the -page offsets as desired

Comment: That is one I tried, it just presents a white rectangle the size of marker.svg :(
Here are links to the two image files:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NIi7WDuko7aQ-htSNESjKL4ErCi9rtHv (face.png)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MxxgpbuET18ghqYwNglSkXUAXELmxaPB (marker.svg). The second script (with -page) is one I copied and revised from the IM documentation - putting push pins on a map.

Comment: See my CORRECTION in my answer above. The issue is that the -compose copy_opacity flows over to the -flatten. So you have to reset to -compose over before flattening

Comment: Nearly brilliant !! When I run the command the circular image is just off to the right and aligned to the top. I can see we have lost the "-page -1+2" which placed the circular image correctly on the marker. How do I achieve this ?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yLWdIMD1xhxWAiYtUrMZvqu3akhy2PpF

Comment: Put the -page -1+2 inside the first parenthesis just before -define ... Then adjust as desired. Sorry, I forgot to put it back in when testing. I have modified my CORRECTION. See above.

Comment: Brilliant !! Many thanks, has been an honour to be helped by you, Fred.

Comment: Dang, I thought I was done... seem to have lost the transparency of marker.svg, can it be retained ?

Comment: Add -background none before the svg file and change your output from jpg to png. JPG does not support transparency. See my changes to my Correction.

Comment: Thanks, we now have two methods :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Changed over to composite from flatten, and just had to find the right place to put the geometry setting. Without the geometry the circular image is placed in the centre of marker.png (svg) so I had to apply a different setting to get it to position correctly:

```
convert marker.png \( -define jpeg:size=200x200 face.png \
 -thumbnail 31x31^ -gravity center -extent 31x31 \( +clone \
 -threshold -1 -negate -fill white -draw 'circle 15,12 12,0' \) \
 -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \) -geometry +0-7 \
 -compose over -composite facemarker.png
```

Found the solution, more or less, on the [push pins on a map forum question](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20251)!

Comment: -page works for me if you put it inside the first parenthesis as I mention above. Also to keep transparency, put -background none before reading the svg file. Not sure why you changed from input as svg to input as png?

Comment: I am working on a possible solution for AppInventor ( I am a "helper" on the forum)  - the map markers are svg by default but other image components will not display svg, that is why I have been switching around a bit. - you have been credited on the forum for your solution :)

Comment: FYI. Imagemagick can use one of 3 SVG renderers in order of increasing quality/reliability: 1) Imagemagick's internal MSVG/XML rendered, 2) RSVG delegate and 3) Inkscape. For best quality/reliability install Inkscape and Imagemagick will use it over the other 2.

Comment: Can AppInventor use Imagemagick? I know nothing about AppInventor before I just did a search on Google for it. Just curious. You can email me offline if you want. My email address is in my profile at my Imagemagick scripts web site.